# How to get picker view with done button when clicking in textfield?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uipickerview

I'm trying to create a textfield that opens a picker view with a done button instead of the keyboard. User selects a category from the picker view and that will populate the textfield when the done button is pressed. I read many posts about this topic and followed those instructions. but I always run in the same problem (see blow).

I have created the pickerView and initialized it with my array. I know that I have to set the inputView of my textFieldCategory to my pickerView. When I run the code everything works fine until I click the Category textfield. Then the app crashes and I get following error output:

015-03-23 19:09:18.663 TestApp[903:63946] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'child view controller: should have parent view controller: but requested parent is: UIInputWindowController: 0x7f83f184d400

Also, did I place the method call (self.textFieldCategory.inputView = self.picker;) to the right location? I think I did, but I keep getting the error. I read several post about this specific error and followed instructions to solve it. but the described cases were a little different and with older versions of xcode.

I don't even looking for anyone showing me the correct code, but if someone could guide me into the right direction, that would be highly appreciated.

Here is what I have so far in my ViewController.m file:

```
#import "AddNewObjectViewController.h"

@interface AddNewObjectViewController ()

{
    NSArray *_pickerData;
}

//IBAction from textFieldName
- (IBAction)editingChanged:(UITextField *)sender;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textFieldName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textFieldCategory;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *saveButton;

@end

@implementation AddNewObjectViewController

- (IBAction)editingChanged:(UITextField *)textFieldName
{
    //Activate saveButton if at least one character is entered in textFieldName
    _saveButton.enabled = textFieldName.text.length > 0;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.



    //disable saveButton
    [_saveButton setEnabled:NO];


    //Initialize Data
    _pickerData = @[@"Category 1", @"Category 2", @"Category 3", @"Category 4"];

    //Connect Data
    self.picker.dataSource = self;
    self.picker.delegate = self;

    self.textFieldCategory.inputView = self.picker;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// The number of columns of data
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

// The number of rows of data
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return _pickerData.count;
}

// The data to return for the row and component (column) that's being passed in
- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return _pickerData[row];
}


#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if (sender != self.saveButton) return;
    if (self.textFieldObjectName.text.length > 0) {
        self.myObject = [[MyObject alloc] init];
        self.myObject.myObjectName = self.textFieldName.text;
        self.myObject.myObjectCategory = self.textFieldCategory.text;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Since this is your first question, I won't don't vote you for, " But I can't get it to work". That's not very useful for people trying to help you. Say what result your code gives, and what you expect. Be specific.

Comment: Where do you create self.picker?

Comment: In my View Controller.h file I have:   @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *picker;

Comment: I just started a quick new project. Created one textfield and one picker view which I initialized with an array. I run in the same problem with the same error. I wanted to find out if when I isolate the text field and picker view if I would still have the problem. and yes, I have. I must have something totally wrong in my approach.

Comment: I was able to solve the first problem of my question. It is not crashing anymore. Now, when I click in the textfield the picker view comes up! Yeah. The solution: I added  [self.picker removeFromSuperview]; under viewDidLoad.....and that did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I just figured out why it crashed. I created the textfield and the pickerView in Storyboard. In order to make it work I had to remove the pickerView from superview:

[self.picker removeFromSuperview];

I added this method under viewDidLoad and now when I click the textfield the app does not crash anymore but brings up the pickerView!